# Adding a separation line to a Tikz graphic

Tags: positioning, tikz-trees

I have a graphics/tree which looks like the following:

[image]

I created this figure using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
    every node/.style = {shape=circle, draw, align=center}]]
    \node [fill=black] {}
        child { node (ja1) [fill=black] {} 
            child { [sibling distance=10em] node (ja2) [fill=black] {}
                child { [sibling distance=5em] node [fill=black] {}
                    child { node (ja4l) [fill=black] {} edge from parent node [left, draw=none] {Ja} }
                    child { node (nein4l) [fill=black] {} edge from parent node [right, draw=none] {Nein} }
                    edge from parent node [left, draw=none] {Ja}} % Dritte Ebene
                child { [sibling distance=5em] node [fill=black] {}
                    child { node (ja4r) [fill=black] {}edge from parent node [left, draw=none] {Ja} }
                    child { node (nein4r) [fill=black] {} edge from parent node [right, draw=none] {Nein} }
                edge from parent node [right, draw=none] {Nein} } % Dritte Ebene
            edge from parent node [left, draw=none] {Ja} } % Zweite Ebene
            child { node (nein2) [fill=black] {} edge from parent node [right, draw=none] {Nein} }
        edge from parent node [left, draw=none] {Ja} } % Erste Ebene
        child { node (nein1) [fill=black] {} edge from parent node [right, draw=none] {Nein}}; % Erste Ebene

    \node (nop) [draw=none, below = of nein1, shape=rectangle, xshift=5em] {Keine Provenance};
    \node (pla) [draw=none, below = of nein2, shape = rectangle, xshift=5em] {Plausibilität};
    \node (nvz) [draw=none, below = of nein4r, shape = rectangle, xshift=2.5em] {Nachvollziehbarkeit};
    \node (rek) [draw=none, below = of ja4r, shape=rectangle, yshift=-2.5em] {Rekonstruierbarkeit};
    \node (snv) [draw=none, below = of nein4l, shape=rectangle, yshift=-p5em] {Starke Nachvollziehbarkeit};
    \node (srk) [draw=none, below = of ja4l, shape=rectangle, xshift=-2.5em] {Starke Rekonstruierbarkeit \\ Fehlernachvollziehbarkeit};


    \draw (nein1) -- (nop);
    \draw (nein2) -- (pla);
    \draw (nein4r) -- (nvz);
    \draw (ja4r) -- (rek);
    \draw (nein4l) -- (snv);
    \draw (ja4l) -- (srk);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My problem is that I want to add a textual condition to this decision tree. Because the condition occures several times (e.g. in four leaves on the left side of the tree) I do not want to add the text of the conditions to the nodes but on the left side of my graphics. Something like this:

[image]

How am I able to archieve this?

Comment: Please, always post complete examples which compile rather than mere fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using only TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    punkt/.style={shape=circle, fill=black},
    nurtext/.style={shape=rectangle, draw=none, fill=none, align=center}
    ]
    \node (root) [punkt] {}
        [every child node/.append style = {punkt},
        sibling distance=10em,
        edge from parent/.append style = {nodes={inner xsep=.75em}},
        level 4/.style={
          sibling distance=5em,
          edge from parent/.append style = {nodes={inner xsep=.5em}}}
        ]
        child { node {} 
            child { node {}
                child {  node {}
                    child { node {}
                        child { node [nurtext] { Starke Rekonstruierbarkeit \\ Fehlernachvollziehbarkeit } }
                        child [missing]
                        edge from parent node [left] {Ja} }
                    child { node {} 
                        child [level distance=2.5cm] { node [nurtext] { Starke Nachvollziehbarkeit } }
                        edge from parent node [right] {Nein} }
                    edge from parent node [left] {Ja}} % Dritte Ebene
                child {  node {}
                    child { node {}
                        child [level distance=2cm] { node [nurtext] { Rekonstruierbarkeit } }
                        edge from parent node [left] {Ja} }
                    child { node {} 
                        child [missing]
                        child { node [nurtext] { Nachvollziehbarkeit } }
                        edge from parent node [right] {Nein} }
                edge from parent node [right] {Nein} } % Dritte Ebene
            edge from parent node [left] {Ja} } % Zweite Ebene
            child { node {}
                child [missing]
                child { node [nurtext] {Plausibiltiät} }
                edge from parent node [right] {Nein} }
        edge from parent node [left] {Ja} } % Erste Ebene
        child { node {} 
            child [missing]
            child { node [nurtext] {Keine Provenance} }
            edge from parent node [right] {Nein} }; % Erste Ebene
    \draw
        (root-1-1-1-1-1.west) coordinate (links)
        (links|-root)--(root)--+(1,0)
        (links|-root-1)--(root-1)--(root-2)--+(1,0)
        (links|-root-1-1)--(root-1-2)--+(1,0)
        (links|-root-1-1-1)--(root-1-1-1)--(root-1-1-2)--+(1,0)
        (links|-root-1-1-1-1)--(root-1-1-1-1)--(root-1-1-1-2)--(root-1-1-2-1)--(root-1-1-2-2)--+(1,0)
    ;
    \path [ nodes={right} ]
        (links|-root)
        --node{Bedingung 1}
        (links|-root-1)
        --node{Bedingung 2}
        (links|-root-1-1)
        --node{Bedingung 3}
        (links|-root-1-1-1)
        --node{Bedingung 4}
        (links|-root-1-1-1-1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses an experimental package based on `forest` called `justtrees` (version 0.05). If you are interested, let me know.

**EDITED** to add in the separation lines and improve spacing and alignment.

Basically, it lets you specify the tree and the annotations in something like the following way.

```
  [, left just=, right just=, name=n1
    [, left just=Condition 1, right just=, name=n2
      [, left just=Condition 2, right just=, name=n3
        [, left just=Condition 3, right just=, name=n4
          [, left just=Condition 4, right just=, name=n5
            [Starke Rekonstruierbarkeit\\Fehlernachvollziehbarkeit]
          ]
          [
            [[[Starke Nachvollziehbarkeit]]]
          ]
        ]
        [
          [
            [[Rekonstruierbarkeit]]
          ]
          [
            [,phantom]
            [Nachvollziehbarkeit]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
        [Plausibilität]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
      [Keine Provenance]
    ]
  ]
```

Empty `left just` and `right just` are added where we want empty nodes created for the purpose of drawing the separation lines. If we actually want an annotation at this level, we say `left just=<annotation>`. `phantom` nodes are just to help with the placement of sibling nodes, where we don't want an only child directly below its parent.

The appearance of the tree is customised in the following way. For repeated use, this could obviously be wrapped in a style for convenience.

Adjust alignment of annotations:

```
      just format={yshift=.75\baselineskip},
```

configure the style of the nodes etc. conditionally, according to level etc.:

```
      for tree={
        align=center,
        if level=1{
          before typesetting nodes={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.5pt}
        }{},
        if n children=0{
          yshift=5pt,
        }{
          parent anchor=center,
          child anchor=center,
          if n children=2{
            for children={
              if n children=0{}{
                before typesetting nodes={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.5pt},
                if n=1{% create the 'Ja' and 'Nein' labels
                  edge label={node [midway, left, xshift=-5pt] {Ja}}
                }{
                  if n'=1{
                    edge label={node [midway, right, xshift=5pt] {Nein}}
                  }{}
                },
              }
            }
          }{},
        }{}
      },
```

Draw in the separation lines:

```
      end draw/.code={
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
          \draw (left just 2.south west |- n\i) coordinate (this \i) -- (right just \i.south west |- this \i);
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
```

The result looks something like this:

[image: just a tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{justtrees}% version 0.05
\begin{document}
\begin{justtree}
    {
      just format={yshift=.75\baselineskip},
      for tree={
        align=center,
        if level=1{
          before typesetting nodes={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.5pt}
        }{},
        if n children=0{
          yshift=5pt,
        }{
          parent anchor=center,
          child anchor=center,
          if n children=2{
            for children={
              if n children=0{}{
                before typesetting nodes={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=2.5pt},
                if n=1{
                  edge label={node [midway, left, xshift=-5pt] {Ja}}
                }{
                  if n'=1{
                    edge label={node [midway, right, xshift=5pt] {Nein}}
                  }{}
                },
              }
            }
          }{},
        }{}
      },
      end draw/.code={
        \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
          \draw (left just 2.south west |- n\i) coordinate (this \i) -- (right just \i.south west |- this \i);
        }
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }
  [, left just=, right just=, name=root, name=n1
    [, left just=Condition 1, right just=, name=n2
      [, left just=Condition 2, right just=, name=n3
        [, left just=Condition 3, right just=, name=n4
          [, left just=Condition 4, right just=, name=n5
            [Starke Rekonstruierbarkeit\\Fehlernachvollziehbarkeit]
          ]
          [
            [[[Starke Nachvollziehbarkeit]]]
          ]
        ]
        [
          [
            [[Rekonstruierbarkeit]]
          ]
          [
            [,phantom]
            [Nachvollziehbarkeit]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [
        [,phantom]
        [Plausibilität]
      ]
    ]
    [
      [,phantom]
      [Keine Provenance]
    ]
  ]
\end{justtree}
\end{document}
```